# Talmid that is an Avel going to a wedding of his Rebbe

Tags: halacha, rabbis, mourning-aveilus, wedding

I had heard once that there is a [Teshuvas Ranach](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1234&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) that says it's [muter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) for a student that is an avel (in the year of mourning) to go to a wedding that his [Rebbe](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/593) is making for one his children. I haven't located the teshuva. Perhaps someone knows where this is, or knows other poskim who discuss (and do in fact permit) this?

(I believe the reasoning was is that a student is like a son. All of this I simply once heard and never saw anything inside so it's all speculation. However this is why I'm asking.)

Comment: The wedding is one of the **rebbe's** children's, I assume?

Comment: The mourning is for a parent, I assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nit'e Gavriel* (*Avelus* 16:15) says:

> One can be lenient and join the *simcha* of his rebbe, including of the rebbe's descendants, provided the conditions of paragraph 9 are met.

Those conditions are that he not eat at the meal, that he do some labor at the meal [like a waiter] to serve as a marker that he's in mourning, and that he not dance. (In paragraph 10 he says also to absent oneself when there is dance music.)

The footnote on paragraph 15 reads:

> So it seems from [*T'shuvos Raanach* (*Mayim Amukim* 50)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1962&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=), who wrote that one can be lenient and join the *simcha* of his rebbe's son, as reverence of one's rebbe should be like reverence of Heaven and honor for one's rebbe is better than honor for one's parents… so [here] the honor of his parents is deferred for the honor of the rebbe…. This is cited in *Tov Leches* (on *Shulchan Aruch*, laws of mourning 391:3). *L'shon Chachamim* (on laws of mourning, 30) says there's a *mitzva* to join the *simcha* of one's rebbe, so can do so in the manner described. Likewise, *Sh'elos Usshuvos M'lamed L'hoil* 143 wrote one's rebbe is like a relative.